# Is it possible to configure EF core "ON UPDATE" behaviour for foreign keys?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-core-2.2

When setting up a foreign key on a child entity like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasOne(c => c.Parent)
    .WithMany(p => p.Children)
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I am able to configure the "ON DELETE" behaviour of the constraint. The resulting migration looks something like:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Child",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),
        ParentId = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Child_Parent_ParentId",
            column: x => x.ParentId,
            principalTable: "Parent",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);                    
    });
```

In the generated migration, I would be able to edit the onUpdate behaviour directly, as can be seen in the method signature:

```
public virtual OperationBuilder<AddForeignKeyOperation> ForeignKey(
      [NotNull] string name,
      [NotNull] Expression<Func<TColumns, object>> column,
      [NotNull] string principalTable,
      [NotNull] string principalColumn,
      [CanBeNull] string principalSchema = null,
      ReferentialAction onUpdate = ReferentialAction.NoAction,
      ReferentialAction onDelete = ReferentialAction.NoAction);
```

but I am unable to find a way to do this through the fluent API or with attributes.

Is it possible to configure EF Core "ON UPDATE" behaviour for foreign keys?

Comment: You can't. And it doesn't makes sense because EF Core does not support mutable keys.

Comment: Why? Modifying primary keys is a *very* strong smell in the first place. They don't need to change unless they contain business data which they *shouldn't*. That's why there's an `OnDelete` but no `OnUpdate`. You can add this to the database yourself but again, why do that?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos First, OP is not asking "why", but "is it possible". Second (which you should agree is confusing), if that's "why there is no `OnUpdate` fluent API, then *why* there *is* `onUpdate` parameter in migration API? I would assume it's "just in case" they decide to support it some day. Or to allow updating outside EF.

Comment: @IvanStoev Is correct. I designed the MigrationsBuilder APIs based on the SQL standard. This lets you manually do a lot of things that don't exactly make sense in EF Core today. But that can change over time. For example, starting in 3.0 entity types can map to tables without a primary key and Migrations will create them. You've been able to manually create tables without primary keys since 1.0. Mutable keys are tracked by issue [#4073](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4073).

Comment: @bricelam Hey, this (except the part referring to my opinion) sounds like a perfect answer rather than comment! Especially by the person who did it.

Comment: lol, fine......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible from the Fluent API today.

We (the EF team) designed the MigrationBuilder APIs based on the SQL spec. This lets you manually do a lot of things that don't exactly make sense in EF Core today. But that can change over time. For example, starting in 3.0 entity types can map to tables without a primary key and Migrations will create them. You've been able to manually create tables without primary keys since 1.0.

When mutable keys are enabled (issue [#4073](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4073)) there will likely be Fluent API introduced to let you configure the ON UPDATE behavior.

Comment: And it appears this has still not been implemented?

Comment: @JonathanWood, yes, here is an issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21563